# Restoring flat tables after truncate

Tags: magento-1.9, database, reindex, flat-catalog, flat-indexer

I am planning to truncate `catalog_product_flat_*` tables to fix the Catalog Serach Index per this StackOverflow answer.

[“There was a problem‍​​ with reindexing process.” after product import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304574/there-was-a-problem-with-reindexing-process-after-product-import/9849248#9849248)

In the case that after the truncate, the reindex continues to fail, should I restore the `catalog_product_flat_*` tables or the entire database?

Comment: I thought a full re-index would re-create flat tables? as it populates these tables from various other entity tables to enable performance increase

Comment: @RickyOdinMatthews yes, but there's an issue where reindex is failing. Truncating these tables should fix the issue, but in the case it doesn't, I'd like to know how to restore the database.

Comment: What is the error showing when perform the re-index ?

Comment: Did you try reindexing from shell?

Comment: @duke Error is "There was a problem‍​​ with reindexing process.”. I don't see anything more specific in any of the Apache or Magento logs.

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis yes, same issue.

Comment: In a similar problem I dropped the flat tables and they were recreated by the indexing. Make sure you backup first.

Comment: If you have lots of attributes that are filterable or shown on frontend you may have reached the SQL table size limit.  If so then catalog_product_flat will never complete the re-index process.  See https://www.sonassi.com/blog/magento-kb/mysql-limitations-on-the-flat-catalogue-in-magento